# $A,B$:Hermitian matrices with $A^k=B^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to show the following problem from linear algebra:

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $A,B\in M_n$ be Hermitian matrices.
>   If all eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are positive and $A^k=B^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $A=B$.

I could understand that if $C$ is a Hermitian matrix, then eigenvalues of $C$ are real, and if $k=1$, then the statement is clear.

But I could not go further. I appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Hint.* You can define the $k$-th root of any positive semi-definite Hermitian matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\ker(A-\lambda I_n)\subset \ker (A^k-\lambda^k I_n)$$
and since $A$ is Hermitian then diagonalizable so
$$n=\dim\Bbb C^n=\sum_{\lambda\in\operatorname{Sp}(A)}\dim\ker(A-\lambda I_n)$$ 
Moreover, since $\lambda^k$ are distinct then $\sum\ker(A^k-\lambda^k I_n$) is a direct sum and so from the first inclusion we see that in fact
$$\ker(A-\lambda I_n)=\ker(A^k-\lambda^k I_n)$$
The same reasoning for $B$ gives us finally
$$\ker(A-\lambda I_n)=\ker(B-\lambda I_n)$$
and since $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable we get $A=B$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But where did you use the hypothesis that eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: The eigenvalues are positive then $\lambda^k$ are distinct whatever the value of $k$.